# On arch linux ping on gateway but not on 8.8.8.8

Tags: linux, arch-linux

When I ping gateway, I have 100% success, but `ping 8. 8. 8. 8` results in 100% loss, as does `ping www.google.com`.

Any ideas what's going on?

```
#ip link set etho up
#ip addr add (ip)/(natemask) broadcast (broadcast id) dev etho
#ip route add difault via ( gateway) 

#ping <ip>
ok
#ping <gateway>
ok
#ping 8.8.8.8
100% loss
#ping www.google.com
100% loss
```

Comment: It sounds as though you simply have no internet connection. Please post the output of `ifconfig` or `iwconfig` if you have wireless.\

Comment: wire...   [root@103 suprokash]# ip -s route add default via 172.17.81.129
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
[root@103 suprokash]# ip -s mroute add default via 172.17.81.129
Command "add" is unknown, try "ip mroute help".
[root@103 suprokash]# ip route
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eno1  proto static 
172.17.81.128/25 dev eno1  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.17.81.183 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eno1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.15  metric 1 
[root@103 suprokash]# ip mroute
[root@103 suprokash]# ip -s route add default via 172.17.81.129
RTNETLINK answers: File exists

Answer (score 0):

Your gateway is not connected to Internet.

Comment: how i connet gateway

Comment: how i change may static route ip

Comment: It depends on your Internet service. It can be ADSL, optical fiber... that connect your gateway to Internet via ISP infrastructure

Comment: ethernet wire, how i change static gateway , DHCP , in arch linux